# C -Struct array, problems with free, problems with assigning values in my struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, valgrind

What follows is my program. I'm creating a struct, using malloc to allocate memory because I want a very large struct array, and then passing that struct array to functions. The functions aren't important, because I can't get out of the main program. My confusion is my compiler (gcc) saying that each_event is undeclared when I try to free it, but nowhere else. When I comment out the free statement it compiles, but then valgrind says I have an invalid write of size 4 when I do the each_event[i].timestamp = tim[i] line. The line above that is commented out because valgrind was telling me the error was there (I compiled with gcc -g -O0) even though I knew it had to mean the line below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define event_length 512
#define bits_n_byte 8
#define timestamp_bytes 8

typedef enum type {
    DATA, CLOCK, EXPECTED, SPILL, ALL
} type;

typedef struct event {
char clocbuffer[event_length*bits_n_byte];
char datbuffer[event_length*bits_n_byte];
char expect[event_length];
char spil[event_length];
char clocerror[event_length*bits_n_byte];
char daterror[event_length*bits_n_byte];
long unsigned int timestamp;
} event;

int i, j, k, l, length, nevents;
char **spil, **expect, **dat, **cloc, **clocerror, **daterror;
long unsigned int *tim;
char library[256];
char *runnum, *clocmode, *datmode;

void GetPiece(char*, type, struct event*);
void FindMode(type);
void ErrorPiece(type);

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
if (argc != 2) {fprintf(stderr, "Format: ./program #_patterns\nTry again.\n");}

for (i=0;i<256;i++) library[i]=i;

FILE *IN = NULL;
char *buffer = NULL;

runnum = (char *) malloc(2);
runnum = strncpy(runnum,argv[1],1);
runnum[1] = '\0';
IN=fopen(argv[1], "r");                 /*Open input file.*/

if (IN)
{
    fseek(IN, 0, SEEK_END);                 /*This finds  */
    length  = ftell(IN);                    /*the length  */
    fseek(IN, 0, SEEK_SET);                 /*of the file.*/
    buffer = malloc(length + 2);            /*for buffer.     */
    fread(buffer, 1, length, IN);
    tim = (long unsigned int *) malloc(length + 2*sizeof(long unsigned int));
    fread(tim, sizeof(long unsigned int), length/sizeof(long unsigned int), IN);
    fclose(IN);

    nevents = length/2056;
    struct event* each_event = (struct event *) malloc(nevents*sizeof(struct event));

    for (i=0; i<length/sizeof(unsigned long int); i+=2056/sizeof(unsigned long int))
    {
    tim[i] = __builtin_bswap32 (tim[i]);
    tim[i]-=0x80000000;
    //if (tim[i]<1200000000 || tim[i]>1300000000) fprintf(stderr, "Check timestamp. Either endianness, size of bytes, or size of long ints are different.");
    each_event[i].timestamp = tim[i];
    }

    clocmode = malloc(nevents);
    datmode = malloc(nevents);

    GetPiece(buffer, DATA, each_event);
    GetPiece(buffer, CLOCK, each_event);
    GetPiece(buffer, EXPECTED, each_event);
    GetPiece(buffer, SPILL, each_event);
    GetPiece(buffer, ALL, each_event);
    FindMode(DATA);
    FindMode(CLOCK);
    ErrorPiece(DATA);
    ErrorPiece(CLOCK);
}
else fprintf(stderr,"Error in file naming/opening.\n");   /*error*/
free (buffer);
free (tim);
free (runnum);
free (clocmode);
free (datmode);
free (each_event);
return 0;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `each_event` is declared inside the `if { ... }` block, it is out of scope by the time you try to `free()` it. Either free it at the end of the `if { ... }`, or put the declaration in along with the others at the start of `main()`. If you do the latter, though, you will probably get warnings about it possibly being used without being initialized, so the first option is probably best.

Comment: that's exactly it. I thought using malloc and putting that memory on the heap was enough, but I guess the variable name goes away outside of the block. I learn something new at least once an hour!